# sorting contents of file

Tags: c, file, sorting

i am trying to sort the contents of a file by name
here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
struct Contacts
{
    char name[20];
    int phone;
    char address[20];

};


int countLines(FILE * fp);
void sort_contact(int length , FILE * f);
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE *f=fopen("D:\\eman.txt","r");
    int c;
    c=countLines(f);

    printf("number of lines %d",c);


     sort_contact(c ,  f);
    return 0;
}


int countLines(FILE * fp){
    char line[80];
    int counter = 0;
    while ( fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) ){ 


        counter+=1;

    }
    return counter;
}



void sort_contact(int length , FILE * f)
    {
    //  struct Contacts  * eman [length];
        int flag;
        int i; // for loop counter
        struct Contacts con;
        struct Contacts tmp;
        struct Contacts conn;
        struct Contacts users[length];
        //f=fopen("","r";)
        //while( ( fscanf(f, "%s  %d %s ", con.name ,&con.phone,con.address) != EOF) && (length > 0)  )

        while( ( fscanf(f, "%s  %d %s ", users[length].name ,&users[length].phone,users[length].address) != EOF) && (length > 0)  )
            {
                con=users[length];
             conn=users[length--];
                flag=strcmp(con.name,conn.name);
                //length --;


            switch(flag)
            {
                case 1:
                    tmp=users[length--];
                    users[length--]=users[length];
                    users[length]=tmp;
                    break;

                case 0:
                case -1:
                break;  

            }

        length --;
        //seek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    }//end fo while
            fclose(f);
            f=fopen("D:\\eman.txt","+w");
            for(i=length;i>0;i--)
            {
            //  tmp=users[i];
                fprintf(f,"%s %d %s",users[i].name,users[i].phone, users[i].address);
            }
            fclose(f);



 }
```

i put the contents in a structure, then sort the structure by name and add it again to the file 
when i run it, nothing is changed in the file

Comment: What? `iostream` header for a C program?

Comment: 2) `Type array[Size];` access to `array[Size]` is out of bounds.

Comment: `FILE *f=fopen("D:\\eman.txt","r");`...what if `fopen()` fails?

Comment: i tried to change the while loop and put two for loops instead but nothing changed
i want to compare two lines
for(i=0;i<length;i++)
  {
  
   for(j=1;j< length;j++)
   {
    con=users[i];
    conn=users[j];
    flag=strcmp(con.name,conn.name);
    
    
    
    switch(flag)
      {
    case 1:
     tmp=users[length--];
     users[length--]=users[length];
     users[length]=tmp;
     break;
     
    case 0:
    case -1:
    break; 
    
   }

Comment: your code does not really look like a sorting algorithm, also length-- is called three times in the while loop which seems to be incorrect.

Comment: this line: #include <iostream> is for a C++ program, it should be: #include <stdio.h>

Answer (score 1):

```
// the following is a clean compile of your program
// with the algorithm logic corrected (and several other details)
// with checking of returned values from output I/O statements
// with checking of returned value from malloc and calloc
// with modification to the input and output format strings
// Note:
// 1) if the sizing of name and address fields is inadequate
//       for actual values in input file
//       then this algorithm will fail
// 2) if any line in the input file is longer than 80 chars
//       then this algorithm will fail
// 3) when reading a line from the file into pUsers[]
//       it would be far safer (and can validate format of line contents)
//       to read the line into a temporary area like: char line[80]
//       then parse the fields using something like: sscanf()
//       then malformed lines can be recognized/discarded
// suggest breaking the sort_contact() function into three functions:
// 1) read the input file into pUsers[]
// 2) sort pUsers[]
// 3) write the new file


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
struct Contacts
{
    char name[20];  // what if name is longer than 19 char in file
    int phone;
    char address[20]; // what if address is longer than 19 char in file
};

// prototypes
int countLines(FILE *);
void sort_contact(int, FILE *);

// place outside of any function because it could be HUGE,
// depending on input file size
// and do not want to put all that on the stack
static struct Contacts* pUsers = NULL;

int main()
{
    int lineCount = 0;
    FILE *inf=fopen("D:\\eman.txt","r");
    if ( NULL == inf )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed for read of eman.txt" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    lineCount = countLines(inf);

    if( 0 < lineCount )
    {
        printf("number of lines in input file: %d", lineCount);

        // note: using calloc removes need to terminate each string later
        if( NULL == (pUsers = calloc( lineCount, sizeof( struct Contacts ) ) ) )
        { // then calloc failed
            perror( "calloc failed for input array" );
            fclose(inf);
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful

        sort_contact(lineCount, inf);

        free( pUsers ); // cleanup
    }

    else
    {
        printf( "no lines read from input file\n" );
    }

    fclose( inf );  // cleanup

    return 0;
} // end function: main


int countLines(FILE * inf)
{
    char line[80]; // what if some line is greater than 79 characters or contains nulls?
    int counter = 0;
    while ( fgets(line, sizeof line, inf) )
    {
        counter+=1;
    } // end while

    rewind( inf ); // cleanup

    return counter;
} // end function: countLines


void sort_contact(int lineCount, FILE * inf)
{
    int i = 0;           // write loop counter
    int currentLine = 0; // read loop counter
    int retFscanf=0;     // returned value from fscanf

    int c; // outer sort loop counter
    int d; // inner sort loop counter

    struct Contacts tmp;

    // read all lines from file into pUsers array
    for( currentLine=0; currentLine < lineCount; currentLine++)
    {
        retFscanf = fscanf(inf, " %19s %d %19s", // note leading space in format string, no trailing space
              pUsers[currentLine].name ,
              &pUsers[currentLine].phone,
              pUsers[currentLine].address);
        if( 3 != retFscanf )
        { // then, fscanf failed
            perror( "fscanf failed" );
            fclose( inf );  // cleanup
            free( pUsers ); // cleanup
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fscanf successful
    } // end for

    // implement bubble sort here

    for (c = 0 ; c < ( lineCount-1 ); c++)
    { // whole array

        for (d = 0 ; d < (lineCount - c - 1); d++)
        { // current subset of whole array

            if ( 0 < (strcmp( pUsers[d].name, pUsers[d+1].name  ) ) )
            { // then, earlier name sorts after next name
                memcpy( &tmp,         &pUsers[d],   sizeof( struct Contacts) );
                memcpy( &pUsers[d],   &pUsers[d+1], sizeof( struct Contacts ));
                memcpy( &pUsers[d+1], &tmp,         sizeof( struct Contacts) );
            } // end if
        } // end for
    } // end for

    FILE * outf;
    if( NULL == (outf = fopen("D:\\eman.txt","+w") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed for write" );
        free( pUsers ); // cleanup
        fclose( inf );    // cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // endif

    // implied else fopen successful

    for(i=0;i<lineCount;i++)
    {
            fprintf(outf,"%s %d %s\n",pUsers[i].name, pUsers[i].phone, pUsers[i].address);
    } // end for

    fclose( outf ); // cleanup
} // end function: sort_contact
```

Comment: Instead of reading the contents of a file to an array (after adequately allocating), and after sorting the contents within the array, and then writing them back to the file, may we use a memory-mapped file and swap the contents within the file itself (provided each record or line within the file is of fixed size)

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana,  The functionality can be implemented in many different ways.  I chose to stick with the algorithm (and other limits) provided by the OP so it would be easy for the OP to understand what is being done.

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana — you could use a memory-mapped file, but it is not guaranteed to be quicker than reading from file into memory, sorting in memory, and writing back to file.  Indeed, it might be slower if the file doesn't readily fit into the working set memory available for the process (so intermediate values have to be written to disk, and retrieved from disk, increasing the I/O).  Reading the file from disk into memory probably reduces the risk of that happening.  You can sort chunks of the file if need so be, writing intermediate results to disk, and then merging the results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [qsort()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm) function?

```
int compare_contact (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  Contacts* left = (Contacts*) a;
  Contacts* right = (Contacts*) b;
  return strncmp(left.name,right.name, sizeof Contacts.name);
}
```

`qsort(pUsers, length, sizeof Contacts, compare_contact);`